# EGL/OpenGL ES/switching context is slow

Tags: opengl-es, egl

I am developing an OpenGL ES 2.0 application (using angleproject on Windows for developement) that is made up of multiple 'frames'.

Each frame is an isolated application that should not interfere with the surrounding frames. The frames are drawn using OpenGL ES 2.0, by the code running inside of that frame.

My first attempt was to assign a frame buffer to each frame. But there was a problem - OpenGL's internal states are changed while one frame is drawing, and if the next frame doesn't comprehensively reset every known OpenGL state, there could be possible side effects. This defeats my requirement that each frame should be isolated and not affect one another.

My next attempt was to use a context per frame. I created a unique context for each frame. I'm using sharing resources, so that I can eglMakeCurrent to each frame, render each to their own frame buffer/texture, then eglMakeCurrent back to globally, to compose each texture to the final screen.

This does a great job at isolating the instances, however.. eglMakeCurrent is *very* slow. As little as 4 of them can make it take a second or more to render the screen.

What approach can I take? Is there a way I can either speed up context switching, or avoid context switching by somehow saving the OpenGL state per frame?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that may eliminate the overhead of eglMakeCurrent while allowing you to use your current approach.

The concept of current EGLContext is thread-local. I suggest creating all contexts in your process's master thread, then create one thread per context, passing one context to each thread. During each thread's initialization, it will call eglMakeCurrent on the context it owns, and never call eglMakeCurrent again. Hopefully, in ANGLE's implementation, the thread-local storage for contexts is implemented efficiently and does not have unnecessary synchronization overhead.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is trying to do this in a generic platform and OS independent way.  If you choose a specific platform, there are good solutions.  On Windows, there are the wgl and glut libraries that will give you multiple windows with completely independent OpenGL contexts running concurrently.  They are called Windows, not Frames.  You could also use DirectX instead of OpenGL. Angle uses DirectX. On linux, the solution is X11 for OpenGL.  In either case, it's critical to have quality OpenGL drivers.  No Intel Extreme chipset drivers.  If you want to do this on Android or iOS, then those require different solutions.  There was a recent thread on the Khronos.org OpenGL ES forum about the Android case.

Comment: The problem with eglMakeCurrent exists on many platforms even when using the platform-provided EGL and OpenGL ES libraries directly, bypassing ANGLE. The fundamental problem is that eglMakeCurrent is often an expensive call, because the EGL specification effectively requires the driver to internally call glFlush before eglMakeCurrent returns. glFlush can burn a lot of CPU. The EGLContext swap also thrashes on the driver's validation of its internal GL state machine.